# A question related to Chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

> Suppose that the dependent variables $z$ and $w$ are functions of independent variables $x$ and $y$, defined by the equations $f(x,y,z(x),w(y))=0$ and $g(x,y,z(x),w(y))=0$, where $$f_zg_w-f_wg_z=1.\tag{*}$$ Then what is expression of $z_x$?

If I multiply $f_zg_w-f_wg_z=1$ with $z_x$, I get $f_zz_xg_w-f_wg_zz_x=z_x$ ie $f_xg_w-f_wg_x=z_x$.

But if I totally differentiate $f$ and $g$ respectively, then $f_z=-\frac{f_x}{z_x}$ and $g_z=-\frac{g_x}{z_z}$. Plugging this in equation $(*)$, I get $f_wg_x-f_xg_w=z_x$

Which one is correct answer? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f_x+f_zz_x=0$ and $g_x+g_zz_x=0$, your first try is missing two minus signs: 
$$f_zz_xg_w-f_wg_zz_x=z_x\implies -f_xg_w-(-f_wg_x)=z_x,$$
so your two results are the same.

Comment: Oh! so why can't we write $f_zz_x=f_x$, just like that?

Comment: Because there are implicit evaluations of the partial derivatives of $f$: the equality correctly written would be $f_x(x,y,z(x),w(y))+f_z(x,y,z(x),w(y))z_x(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!